# sails.io.js - disconnect from "Resourceful PubSub"

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, sails.js

I'm building a single page web application, using [sails.js](http://sailsjs.org) in the backend, and the sails `socket.io.js` socket io wrapper to connect.

I've got a little helper class to let me subscribe to my models:

```
subscribe(model, next) {
    io.socket.get('/' + model, function serverResponded (body, JWR) {

        if (JWR.statusCode == 200) {
            next(null, body, JWR.headers);
        }

        next('The socket server responded with a bad status code ' + (JWR.statusCode), null, JWR.headers);
    });
}
```

So this works (I think, not sure how I get updates pushed to me though :s), however, when the user changes page in my web app, how am I supposed to disconnect from this "subscription" and not stay connected, since its single page?

I see `io.socket.disconnect()` but not sure how I can fit it in.